# How to create arrays of every foreach loop key

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create array after every foreach loop entry.

```
    foreach ($cdatos as $key => $value)
    {
        $chakde .= "array('".$key."',".$value."),";
    }

$p->data = array(array(rtrim($chakde,',')));
```

In the place of "$chakde" i want the 'array("abc",12),array("xyz",20)'. But right now my above logic is not working because its considering array as a comment. I want the data like:

```
$p->data = array(array(array('Heavy Industry', 12),array('Retail', 9), array('Light Industry', 14), array('Out of home', 16),array('Commuting', 7), array('Orientation', 9)));
```

Please help me.

Comment: How about `$chakde []= [$key, $value];`?

Answer (score 0):

Use this solution:

```
      foreach ($cdatos as $key => $value)
      {
    $chakde[] = array($key, $value);
      }
```

$p->data = $chakde;

Answer (score 0):

Declare 2 array. and use **array_push()**
check if this fits on your needs.

```
$data = array();
$chakde = array();
foreach ($cdatos as $key => $value)
{
    $row = ($key => $value);
    array_push($chakde, $row);
    array_push($data , $chakde);
}

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

just make `$p->data` the array directly within the loop

```
foreach ($cdatos as $key => $value) 
{
    $p->data[] = array($key => $value);
}
```

or just set

```
$p->data = $cdatos;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is two differents way among many others :

```
$chakde = array(); 

foreach ($cdatos as $key => $value){
    $chakde[] = array($key=>$value);
}

$p->data = $chakde;
```

Second

```
foreach ($cdatos as $key => $value){
    $chakde[$key] = $value;
}

$p->data = $chakde;
```